# Why is shikashi wrong here?

Tags: grammar

> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesuga, **shikashi** soreha
> shinjitsudesu.

My Japanese is horrible. It's funny, but it's the truth.

I am trying to understand why but is not correct here. People omit shikashi, when do they use shikashi then? Is it omitted because of a stylistic reason or grammar reason?

Comment: You are using two different words for but here. You wouldn't normally say 'but, however,' in English, would you?

Comment: Ah didn't notice it. Should I delete the question? Can we say omoshiroi, shikashi soreha shijitsudesu?

Comment: I wouldn’t say it’s wrong. At least, it’s not the first thing I would correct in that text. I would suggest you say *watashi no nihongo **wa** heta desu* or *… **wa** jōzu dewa/ja arimasen*.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, because you **reduplicated** the meaning of "but".

> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesu**ga**, **shikashi** soreha shinjitsudesu.
> 私の日本語は悪いです。面白いです**が**、**しかし**それは真実です。

Both `ga` and `shikashi` has the meaning of 'but' or 'however', and you should only be using one, not both at the same time. So the following would be correct :

> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesu**ga**, soreha shinjitsudesu.
> My Japanese is bad. Although funny, but it's the truth.

> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesu. **Shikashi**, soreha shinjitsudesu. 
> My Japanese is bad. It's funny. However, it's the truth.

There are two other options to mean `but`: `けど kedo` and `でも demo`. `Kedo` is used like `ga` and affixes to the end of sentence, whereas `demo` is like `shikashi` and has to go in front of the sentence.

> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesu**kedo**, soreha shinjitsudesu.
> Watashi no nihongo ga warui desu. Omoshiroidesu. **Demo**, soreha shinjitsudesu.